# Java - Best Strategy For Appending and Deleting In Giant Lists?

Tags: java, performance, list

Using **Java**.

I record small objects for some calculation etc. and I need only the last x thousand of them. So I'd like to release the first to the garbage collector. But since deleting from ArrayLists is expensive ...

The following is important (can't change)

- no DB
- objects are the same type
- up to 50,000 objects per second
- performance important
- quick iteration through the whole list is important
- random access is also important

This can be changed:

- right now using `ArrayList<MyObject>`
- limit: 100,000 objects (stops recording, but must continue)

My guesses:

- LinkedList
- RingBuffer
- ???

**What can I do to iterate very quick and release old objects also quick at the same time ?**

Comment: you can use hash map or tree map if you can make your data (key - value) format for better performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A solution

... **If you need a constant amount of last elements**, just use an array as a base for a ring buffer.

- single allocation
- no get/put/etc. method overhead if inlined
- simple

A sample (may not compile, written on the fly) implementation:

```
class LastElementsStore<T> {
  Object[] arr;
  int size;
  int nextPutIndex;

  LastElementsStore(int size ) {
    arr = new Object[size];
    this.size = size;
  }

  void put(T elt) {
    arr[nextPutIndex] = elt;
    nextPutIndex++;
    if (nextPutIndex == size) {
      nextPutIndex = 0;
    }
  }

  // getters of your choice

}
```

If there are not enough elements, nulls will be returned.

If you need them ordered, you start from nextPutIndex, read till the end, then go to 0 and continue reading.

You have full control of the memory, no additional node allocations will be made as in LinkedList, no resizing as in ArrayList.

**Old objects are released automatically** as soon as your reach the limit.

### Your requirements

- no DB -- done, just an array used
- objects are the same type -- simple template
- up to 50,000 objects per second -- if an array can't handle it, nothing in Java can
- performance important -- as above, no additional overhead in accessing an array
  quick iteration through the whole list is important -- as fast an iteration as possible
- random access is also important -- the data is ordered, and the first not-null element at/after `nextPutIndex` is the first available

Comment: Since array list is used through the whole project I will do that a little different: extend ArrayList<t> and override methods to make it store items in a ring. Then for performance reasons I might remove ArrayList from extend and make sure it still works fine like you suggested with a direct array.

Comment: @mini-me Do not extend `ArrayList`! - extending collections is a bad practice. Create an internal `ArrayList` field and delegate your functions to it.

Comment: Can you give reasons ? I find it hard **just** to believe.

Comment: @mini-me I can't google it now:/ There was an issue with an extended collection which would cause double element addition in some cases; the general problem is that you don't know the internals of the collections and you may encounter an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Found 1 pro and 1 contra. Pro: ensureCapacity is bugged on Linux, Contra: can't create `T[] a = new T[100];` ("error: Cannot create a generic array of T").

Comment: Right, i didn't know about that; I edited my answer. It doesn't really matter what kind of array you have, you enforce the type through generics. So I changed it to Object[].

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing any of your other requirements, some type of linked list would seem appropriate. Just keep track of the first element (the "head" in list-speak) and the last (the "tail"). Each linked element refences the next. Add to the tail, and remove from the head.

Adding and removing will be very fast (`O(1)`), and iterating will also be very simple.

However, if you need random access to elements, then this solution will perform poorly.

**EDIT**

Since you've added that you need to have random access, a linked list won't work. If the maximum number of objects at any given time is fixed, you could use an `ArrayList` (or a basic Java array) and treat it as a wrap-around buffer. Once you reach the end, start replacing objects from the beginning, and keep track of the index that represents the logical start of the list. (If you use a basic array, you will also need to track how many elements are currently in the buffer -- the equivalent to `List.size()`).

As you replace objects at the beginning of the buffer, the old objects will be automatically released and garbage-collected (as long as they aren't referenced elsewhere).

Comment: Sorry forgot: random access is also important.

Answer (score 3):

I would use an array, and implement an RingBuffer. 
I have done this, but used many unit test to make sure it always works.
I did not found a suitable ring buffer for my needs, maybe you have more luck.